# Easiest way to implement Grid system with Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid-system

I'm already overwhelmed by the whole ecosystem around a React App and I want to take the easiest (and decent) way to use a grid system with Material-UI.

Which one is it and how to use it in a few words?

(I read quite a lot on this topic but still not sure, that's why I'm asking this exact questions)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An easy gird system for react is [React Flexbox Grid](http://roylee0704.github.io/react-flexbox-grid/). Code snippets are on [GitHub](https://github.com/roylee0704/react-flexbox-grid#code-snippets)

It's working nice with [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something really lightweight and straight forward you can use https://github.com/ThisIsDallas/Simple-Grid

Simple Grid is just a *.css* document that you copy into your styles folder, you don't have to install anything via npm.

This grid system isn't built on Flexbox though, just a note.